# PIL installation error on Mac OS Maverics inside virtual env

Tags: pip, python-imaging-library, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install PIL inside virtual as below

```
pip intall PIL
```

And i got the below error

```
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Running setup.py egg_info for package PIL
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

Installing collected packages: PIL
  Running setup.py install for PIL
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
    --- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
    building '_imagingft' extension
    cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -pipe -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imagingft.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imagingft.o
    _imagingft.c:73:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found
    #include <freetype/fterrors.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/build/PIL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/pip-R5JSVs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/include/site/python2.7:
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks

building '_imagingft' extension

cc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -pipe -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imagingft.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imagingft.o

_imagingft.c:73:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found

#include <freetype/fterrors.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/build/PIL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x1/1bwt313j0qvgdh5pfzpbpvcw0000gn/T/pip-R5JSVs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/build/PIL
```

So how to fix it and can some one let me know why it is throwing me an error on my new macbook air ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try Pillow, the fork of PIL. I've not tried in a virtual machine but on Mac OS X you can do this:

```
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2

pip install Pillow
```

Full details here: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation